# Can't write in NTFS shared drive

Tags: mount, ntfs, fstab

i have dual boot (ubuntu and win10) with drive "ARCHIVOS" as ntfs and i want to use this drive in both oses, i got this line in /etc/fstab:

```
#Entry for /dev/sda5 :
UUID=38FEBFFAFEBFAE8E   /media/ARCHIVOS ntfs-3g defaults,locale=es_CO.UTF-8 0   0
```

and tried with:

```
#Entry for /dev/sda5 :
UUID=38FEBFFAFEBFAE8E   /media/ARCHIVOS ntfs-3g defaults    0   0
```

and

```
#Entry for /dev/sda5 :
UUID=38FEBFFAFEBFAE8E   /media/ARCHIVOS ntfs-3g rw,user,exec,umask=000 fmask=000    0   0
```

... and alternating between numbers in fmask | dmask | umask.
i tried with ntfs-config, but nothing works.
¿what to do next?

[EDIT] [SOLVED]
i don't know yet if delete or edit question is correct for this community rules, i edit in case anyone has the same problem:

SOLUTION:

> > go to windows, and go to power options -> aditional power settings -> choose what the power buttons do -> turn off fast startup.
> >     damn windows.
> >     thanks for reading, i hope this is not against community rules.

Comment: I would suggest moving your "solution" to an answer since it worked for you.  In time you can accept it as an answer.  Fast-boot in windows 10 leaves the file-system in an un-closed or incomplete state (some of the data is cached in a hibernate-type file off the file-system, linux detects this & limits access to prevent data loss). This question may be closed due to it being a duplicate, but an unanswered question is not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a laptop and found the same issue.
Trying to mount the ntfs partition gave me an error about the file system in an unclosed state and it mounted read only.
The fix was to do a complete power off on the windows side, not a suspend or shutdown to fast boot mode.